# Google Chrome weird random Cipher Suite

Tags: tls, chrome, ciphers

[This websites](https://cc.dcsec.uni-hannover.de/) gives you information on the SSL cipher suites your browser supports for securing HTTPS connections.

If you browse it with Google Chrome, you'll probably see some weird Cipher Suites in your browser supported Cipher Suites list. (You'll see them in the first suggested Cipher Suite location and also in the extensions section):

look at `baba` in the image below (and also the `3a3a` in the extensions):
[image]

It seems that this number is random. I mean if you refresh the page, those number will change:

look at `dada` in the image below (and also the `1a1a` in the extensions):
[image]

What are these random weird numbers? If those are chrome's proprietary cipher suites (those are not common cipher suites), why should chrome change them randomly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a feature to prevent servers to get buggy. From [GREASE for TLS](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6475903378915328):

> TLS clients offer lists of 16-bit code points (e.g. cipher suites) that servers select from. To remain extensible, servers must ignore unknown values. However, servers may have bugs and reject unknown values. These servers will interoperate with existing clients, so the mistake may spread unnoticed, breaking extensibility for the whole ecosystem. **We will reserve some values to advertise at random**, to prevent such mistakes before broken servers are widespread.

And once you know how it is called you can also [find](https://www.google.com/search?q=grease+tls+boringssl) the feature [in the source code](https://github.com/google/boringssl/blob/master/ssl/handshake_client.cc#L224) of BoringSSL (the OpenSSL fork used by Chrome).

```
  // Add a fake cipher suite. See draft-davidben-tls-grease-01.
  if (ssl->ctx->grease_enabled &&
      !CBB_add_u16(&child, ssl_get_grease_value(ssl, ssl_grease_cipher))) {
    return 0;
  }
```

And the values it will announce can be found [in the internet draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-davidben-tls-grease-01#section-5):

```
  |       Value       | Description | DTLS-OK |    Reference    |
  +-------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------+
  | {TBD} {0x0A,0x0A} |   Reserved  |    Y    | (this document) |
  | {TBD} {0x1A,0x1A} |   Reserved  |    Y    | (this document) |
  | {TBD} {0x2A,0x2A} |   Reserved  |    Y    | (this document) |
  | {TBD} {0x3A,0x3A} |   Reserved  |    Y    | (this document) |
  ...
  | {TBD} {0xEA,0xEA} |   Reserved  |    Y    | (this document) |   
  | {TBD} {0xFA,0xFA} |   Reserved  |    Y    | (this document) |
```

<sub>Note that this answer here is based on my answer to a [similar question in stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200327/why-chrome-use-random-cipher-suites).</sub>

Comment: Are you sure that there is no relation between these random numbers and [Decoy Routing](https://refraction.network/) anti-censorship technique?

Comment: @Abraham: yes, I'm pretty sure. It is a documented behavior. And see edit with a reference to the source code.